# Processing multiple file uploads and writing them to google sheets with JavaScript and Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a form that takes the form data and saves it to a google sheet. The code is below.

I have figured out how to get it to accept a single file and write that link to a cell in a google sheet however, I am stuck trying to figure out how to get it to upload multiple files.

I am using JavaScript and Google Apps Script.The HTML and JavaScript is in the first code snippet and the Google Script code is in the second code snippet.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get a multiple files to upload and save the file url to consecutive cells in the spreadsheet?

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<!-- Introduce Styles -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
  }

  h2 {
    text-align: center;
    /*font-size: 4vh;*/
    margin-top: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #dadce0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 24px;
    padding-top: 22px;
    position: relative;
  }

  fieldset {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border: 1px solid #dadce0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 24px;
    margin-top: 0;
    page-break-inside: avoid;

  }

  legend {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    width: 100%;

  }

  .form-group {}

  input[type="date"],
  input[type="text"] {
    font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
    background-color: (0, 0, 0, 0.54);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #dadce0;
    display: block;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    min-width: 0%;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: .2px;
  }

  select {
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-right: 48px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: .2px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  label {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #help-block {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  #attch_bttn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #dadce0;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #1a73e8;
  }

  #attch_bttn:hover {
    background-color: #1a73e8;
    color: white;
  }

  input[type="file"] {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 26px;
    left: 1px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    outline: none;
  }

  input[type="file"]::-ms-browse {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #dadce0;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #1a73e8;
  }

  input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #dadce0;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #1a73e8;
  }

  #bttn_wrp {
    position: relative;
  }

  input[type="button"] {
    outline: none;
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #dadce0;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #1a73e8;
  }

  input[type="button"]:hover {
    background-color: #1a73e8;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
<!-- End Styles -->

<body>
  <!-- Begin Form -->
  <form id="uploadForm" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxcWkJzUySjqOR7DvwqQssb4I7VkP_yYyWVntdUFCzf4X1bZw/exec" method="POST">
    <h2>PS 108M - Upload a Submittal</h2>
    <!-- Hidden Elements in form Header -->
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="fileContent" id="fileContent">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="filename" id="filename">

    <!-- Spec Section Selector -->
    <fieldset>
      <legend for="spec_sec">Spec Section:</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select required id="spec_sec" name="spec_sec">
          <option value="03120">03120</option>
          <option value="03200">03200</option>
          <option value="05500">05500</option>
          <option value="07115">07115</option>
          <option value="07150">07150</option>
          <option value="08110">08110</option>
          <option value="08710">08710</option>
          <option value="09900">09900</option>
          <option value="10214">10214</option>
          <option value="11300">11300</option>
          <option value="11400">11400</option>
          <option value="15410">15410</option>
          <option value="15411">15411</option>
          <option value="15412">15412</option>
          <option value="15415">15415</option>
          <option value="15416">15416</option>
          <option value="15417">15417</option>
          <option value="15418">15418</option>
          <option value="15451">15451</option>
          <option value="15453">15453</option>
          <option value="15511">15511</option>
          <option value="15516">15516</option>
          <option value="15555">15555</option>
          <option value="15580">15580</option>
          <option value="15592">15592</option>
          <option value="15596">15596</option>
          <option value="15836">15836</option>
          <option value="15852">15852</option>
          <option value="15860">15860</option>
          <option value="15915">15915</option>
          <option value="15974">15974</option>
          <option value="16720">16720</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- End Spec Section Selector -->

    <!-- Begin Revison Nubmer Section -->
    <fieldset>
      <legend for="rev_num">Revision Number:</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input required id="rev_num" type="text" name="rev_num">
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- End Revison Number Section -->

    <!-- Begin Vendor/Subcontractor Section -->
    <fieldset>
      <legend for="vend_sub">Vendor/Subcontractor:</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select required id="vend_sub" name="vend_sub">
          <option value="ITC">ITC</option>
          <option value="1st Heating Solutions">1st Heating Solutions</option>
          <option value="A&amp;L Cesspool">A&amp;L Cesspool</option>
          <option value="AB Environmental">AB Environmental</option>
          <option value="ABC &amp; NY">ABC &amp; NY</option>
          <option value="Able Rigging">Able Rigging</option>
          <option value="Acqua Treat">Acqua Treat</option>
          <option value="ACS">ACS</option>
          <option value="Atco Contracting Group">Atco Contracting Group</option>
          <option value="ATI">ATI</option>
          <option value="B&amp;R">B&amp;R</option>
          <option value="Berco Tank">Berco Tank</option>
          <option value="Big City Boilers">Big City Boilers</option>
          <option value="BRE">BRE</option>
          <option value="Cerco Products">Cerco Products</option>
          <option value="Core Tech">Core Tech</option>
          <option value="Crossroads">Crossroads</option>
          <option value="D&amp;N Services">D&amp;N Services</option>
          <option value="Delta Reliable Cleaning">Delta Reliable Cleaning</option>
          <option value="EAI">EAI</option>
          <option value="EASCO">EASCO</option>
          <option value="First Alert">First Alert</option>
          <option value="GDT">GDT</option>
          <option value="Gregory Reaves">Gregory Reaves</option>
          <option value="H&amp;B Equipment Sales">H&amp;B Equipment Sales</option>
          <option value="High Volt">High Volt</option>
          <option value="Infinity Contracting">Infinity Contracting</option>
          <option value="Island Foundation Corp">Island Foundation Corp</option>
          <option value="J&amp;D Carrying">J&amp;D Carrying</option>
          <option value="Johnson Controls">Johnson Controls</option>
          <option value="Metalline Fire Door Co">Metalline Fire Door Co</option>
          <option value="MLB Door Group">MLB Door Group</option>
          <option value="NK Construction">NK Construction</option>
          <option value="Peak Security">Peak Security</option>
          <option value="Precision General">Precision General</option>
          <option value="Purity Labs">Purity Labs</option>
          <option value="Rockhard Services LLC">Rockhard Services LLC</option>
          <option value="Roebell Painters">Roebell Painters</option>
          <option value="Sam Tell Companies">Sam Tell Companies</option>
          <option value="SPJ Piping">SPJ Piping</option>
          <option value="SRS">SRS</option>
          <option value="Triangle Enterprise">Triangle Enterprise</option>
          <option value="Tristian Contracting">Tristian Contracting</option>
          <option value="Vital Plumbing">Vital Plumbing</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- End Vendor/Subcontractor Section -->

    <!-- Begin Date Submitted Section -->
    <fieldset>
      <legend for="date_sub">Date Submitted:</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="date" id="date_sub" name="date_sub" required>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- End Date Submitted Section -->

    <!-- Begin Date Returned Section -->
    <fieldset>
      <legend for="date_ret">Date Returned:</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="date" id="date-ret" name="date_ret" required>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- End Date Returned Section -->

    <!-- Begin Approval Status Section -->
    <fieldset>
      <legend for="app_stat">Approval Status:</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <p id="help-block">NET / APP - No Exceptions Taken / Approved | MCN / AAN - Make Changes Noted / Approved as Noted | NAT - No Action Taken | RRS - Revise and Resubmit | REJ - Rejected</p>
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="app_stat" id="net_app" value="NET / APP" required>
          <label for="app_stat">NET / APP</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="app_stat" id="mcn_aan" value="MCN / AAN" required>
          <label for="app_stat">MCN / AAN</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="app_stat" id="nat" value="NAT" required>
          <label for="app_stat">NAT</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="app_stat" id="rrs" value="RRS" required>
          <label for="app_stat">RRS</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <input type="radio" name="app_stat" id="rej" value="REJ" required>
          <label for="app_stat">REJ</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- End Approval Status Section -->
    <input type="hidden" name="fvv" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="fbzx" value="6923109898625439205">

    <input type="hidden" name="pageHistory" value="0">

    <!-- Begin File Upload and Submit Section -->
    <fieldset>
      <legend for="attach">Upload Submital:</legend>
      <div id="bttn_wrp">
        <label id="attch_bttn" for="attach"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Add files
          <input required id="attach" name="attach" type="file" multiple />
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input value="Submit" type="button" onclick="UploadFile();" />
    <!-- End File Upload and Submit -->
  </form>
  <!-- End Form -->

  <script>
    function UploadFile() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var file = document.getElementById('attach').files[0];
      reader.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('fileContent').value = reader.result;
        document.getElementById('filename').value = file.name;
        document.getElementById('uploadForm').submit();
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
var emailTo="youremail@gmail.com"

function doPost(e) {
  
  try{
    var data     = e.parameter.fileContent;
    var filename = e.parameter.filename;
    var spec_sec = e.parameter.spec_sec;
    var rev_num  = e.parameter.rev_num
    var result   = uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data,filename,spec_sec,rev_num,e);
    return ContentService //returns json success results
           .createTextOutput(
             JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                             "data": JSON.stringify(result)}))
           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

// new property service GLobal
var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
// see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/

/**
 * select the sheet
 */
function setup() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}

/**
 * record_data inserts the data recieved from the html form submission
 * e is the data recieved from the POST
 */

function record_data(e,fileUrl) {
  try {
    var doc     = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet   = doc.getSheetByName('responses'); // select the responses sheet
    
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; //get next row
    var row     = [ new Date() ]; // first element in the row should always be timestamp
    // loop through header columns
    for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column
      
      if(headers[i].length > 0 && headers[i] == "file") {
        row.push(fileUrl); // add file url to row
      }
      else if(headers[i].length > 0) {
        row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]); // add data top row
      }  
    }
    // more efficent to set values as [][] array than individually
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(e);
  }
  finally {
    return;
  }
  
}

function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, spec_sec, rev_num, e) {
  try {
    var dropbox = "PS 108M - Submittals"
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
    
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    
    var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
        bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
        blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file);
        var file = folder.createFolder([spec_sec, rev_num].join("-")).createFile(blob);
    
        var fileUrl=file.getUrl();
    
        // Generating email Body
        var html = 
      '<body>' +
        '<h2>New Submittal Entered</h2>' +
          '<p>Spec Section : '+e.parameters.spec_sec+'</p>' +
          '<p>Revision Number : '+e.parameters.rev_num+'</p>' +
          '<p>Vendor/Subcontractor : '+e.parameters.vend_sub+'</p>' +
          '<p>Date Submitted : '+e.parameters.date_sub+'</p>' +
          '<p>Date Returned : '+e.parameters.date_ret+'</p>' +
          '<p>Approval Status : '+e.parameters.app_stat+'</p>' +
          '<p><a href='+file.getUrl()+'>Link To Submittal</a></p>' +
       '<body>';
    
       record_data(e,fileUrl);
    
       MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, "New Submittal Entered", "Submittal Entered", {htmlBody:html});
           return file.getUrl();
  } catch (f) {
    return ContentService // return json success results
           .createTextOutput(
             JSON.stringify({"result":"file upload failed",
                             "data": JSON.stringify(f) }))
             .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}
```

Comment: To be sure about what you are requesting for. You want for example in your form to upload 3 files at the same time and submit them in just one run and then in your spreadsheet to appear in each row the images' URL, is that right?

Comment: Yes essentially. The example would be as follows:

 - Upload 3 (or more) files using the file <input> section of the form.

 - The data would be processed and sent to the spreadsheet and stored in corresponding columns.

Currently the link to a single file upload is being stored in the spreadsheet under the files column. I want to be able to store the subsequent file links under 'file_1, file_2, file_3, etc.' columns once they are uploaded.